# Есть ли библиотеки для древовидной структуры данных в Java?

Tags: java, библиотеки, структуры-данных

Есть ли уже готовые реализации деревьев,где можно добавлять новые элементы к каждому конкретному узлу,а не вообще в целом во все дерево?
Я бы мог это и сам реализовать,но не хочется на это тратить время.Есть ли готовые реализации такого?

Comment: Можете привести пример? Что значит "в целом во всё дерево". Все библиотеки, работающие с деревьями позволяют оперировать над отдельными узлами. Вопрос только в том, как Вы эти конкретные узлы определите - как их найдете во всём дереве.

Comment: смотрите Java Collection framework TreeMap

Comment: Я имею ввиду,что бы можно было достать конкретный элемент дерева и добавлять именно к нему потомков.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-tree

Comment: Если я правильно понял статью,то там при добавлении нового элемента автоматически определяется в какое место вставить.Я же хочу,что бы можно было взять конкретный узел дерева и именно к нему добавить новый элемент.

Comment: Да возьмите  Json  и не мучайесь тогда

Comment: Извините,немного не понял.Каким образом тут json?

Comment: щяс в ответ выкачуу

Answer (score 0):

Поработайте с Json togda пример [отсюда](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

```
{
     "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 25,
     "address" : {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city": "New York",
         "state": "NY",
         "postalCode": "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber": [
         { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },
         { "type": "fax", "number": "646 555-4567" }
     ]
 }

JsonObject value = Json.createObjectBuilder()
     .add("firstName", "John")
     .add("lastName", "Smith")
     .add("age", 25)
     .add("address", Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("streetAddress", "21 2nd Street")
         .add("city", "New York")
         .add("state", "NY")
         .add("postalCode", "10021"))
     .add("phoneNumber", Json.createArrayBuilder()
         .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "home")
             .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
         .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "fax")
             .add("number", "646 555-4567")))
```

реализации Json в Java много можете посмотреть. Но смысл тот же

Comment: Это интересный вариант,но все же мне бы хотелось узнать есть ли реализованная структура данных,которую я описал?

Comment: Если json не устраивает то можно почитать про xml.

Comment: И вообще я не сторонник использовать 3 библиотеки без должной рекомендации